# Angular - FormBuilder.group not accepting array of validators

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-formbuilder

I was trying to use extra parameter map provided by Angular FormBuilder

```
group(controlsConfig: {
    [key: string]: any;
}, extra: {
    [key: string]: any;
} | null = null): FormGroup
```

Docs : [FormBuilder](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormBuilder#group)

But facing

> this.validator is not a function

If i pass a single validator instead of an array, the above error vanishes but the validation does not happen?

Can someone help me with this or provide the correct way of using the extra map parameter?

My component and its corresponding template is as follows:

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, Validators, FormGroup, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  formGroupNew: FormGroup;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.createForm();
  }
  createForm() {
    this.formGroupNew = this.fb.group(
      { name:  "Provide name"}, 
     { validator: [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(5)] } );
  }

  validate() {
    console.log(this.formGroupNew.controls["name"].status);
  }
}
```

app.component.html:

```
<div class="container" [formGroup]="formGroupNew">
  <input class="form-control" formControlName="name">
  <button (click)="validate()">Validate</button>
</div>
```

Comment: `name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2)]]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you do `fb.group({...}, {validator: fn})`, the first argument are the controls of the group and the second are configuration parameters for the group object itself, not the controls contained in it.

The error is caused because the method expects to receive a function instead of an array according to the [src](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/5.2x/packages/forms/src/form_builder.ts#L44).

The `ValidatorFn` that you can pass there will be applied to the `FormGroup` object, so you could create custom functions to check for conditions on multiple controls in the group. For that reason it kinda makes no sense to pass something like `Validators.length(5)`, as the value of the group is an object (how would you check that condition against an object?). On the contrary, `Validators.required` makes sense, as the value could be null when all controls aren't set.

Let's say that you have two custom validator functions: `CustomValidatorFnOne`, `CustomValidatorFnTwo` and you want to apply them to the group plus the required. You could do something like:

```
fb.group({...}, {
   validator: Validators.compose(
      [
          CustomValidatorFnOne, 
          CustomValidatorFnTwo,
          Validators.required
      ]
   )
})
```

That way you compose all your validators into one function.